# Отображение слайдов swiper за границами контейнера

Tags: javascript, css, swiper

Очень нужна помощь со слайдером. Задача сделать слайдер swiper который будет выходить за пределы контейнера. Нагуглить ничего не удалось. Приложу рисунок. Имеется сайт с определенным контейнером. Внутри контейнера должно быть четко два слайда. И с каждой стороны контейнера должны показываться части следующих и предыдущих слайдов. Красным обозначен контейнер и зеленым соответственно слайды.

[image: slider]

Comment: Наверное Вам нужно что-то вроде [How to make two center sliders in Swiper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73154335/how-to-make-two-center-sliders-in-swiper)

Comment: Это то что нужно!. Спасибо Вам огромное.